# Yet another Xcode provisioning profile query

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm sick to my back teeth with this whole provisioning business.

After Xcode (4.4.1) got into a state where it would crash on launch I re-installed it. But now after doing so I'm no longer able to  run on hardware as I get a Provisioning Profile can't be found error.

But I don't know what profile its talking about as the id number given in Xcode doesn't mean anything to me. It says

```
Provisioning profile '27F6BCB8-4876-4408-AA16-D749F5B62C2A' can't be found
```

After struggling pointlessly for a while, I've deleted all the profiles from the device and from Xcode and then refreshed them within Xcode and copied them to the device. I have 4 profiles in Xcode, all showing as Valid, they are:

- AdHoc Distribution Profile
- Apple Push Profile
- Project Specific Development Profile
- iOS Team Provisioning Profile

In the provisioning portal Provisioning section there are:
- Apple Push Profile
- Project Specific Development Profile
- iOS Team Provisioning Profile

All 3 of which are showing as being in my Development Certificate profile list.

If I examine any of the profiles in the portal, nowhere can I see any sort of identifier which is of the form ''27F6BCB8-4876-4408-AA16-D749F5B62C2A', so how does one find out which profile Xcode thinks is missing?

If this isn't co-incidental, a few hours ago I added some new device ids to the portal and to the profiles. But I was still able to build/run after doing this and updating/refreshing the profiles. It was only after I had to reinstall Xcode that the problem started.

Right now I'm so fed up, as this isn't the first time I, and I expect countless other's encounter these sorts of problems. But as I don't know what profile Xcode thinks is missing, and things look alright I don't know what else to try to try and sort things out.

Cheers if you can help.

Comment: Have you looked at TN2250 - the code signing troubleshooting guide has a solution for this. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change what profile the app is being code signed against. It is probably set to an old profile that no longer exists. This is done in the targets build settings.

[image]

Comment: This is usually the problem.  Set the signing identity to automatic (recommended).  This way even if you delete a profile, Xcode will be able to find another to use.